# Сортировка массива сразу по двум ключам с приоритетом

Tags: php, массивы

Столкнулся с задачей. Нужно отсортировать многомерный массив сразу по двум значениям.
Есть массив

```
[{"last_season":2,"id":380,"name":"test2","episode_count":6},{"last_season":3,"id":381,"name":"test3","episode_count":11},{"last_season":1,"id":434,"name":"test1","episode_count":7},{"last_season":3,"id":433,"name":"test4","episode_count":9}]
```

Я сортирую массив по ключу last_season при помощи функции

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($b["last_season"], $a["last_season"]);
}
```

На выходе получаю значения last_season от большего к меньшему. Задача отсортировать массив сразу по двум ключам last_season и episode_count, от большего к меньшему, с приоритетом по полю last_season. Если два одинаковых значения у last_season дальше сортировать по episode_count.
На выходе хочу увидеть

```
[{"last_season":3,"id":381,"name":"test3","episode_count":11},{"last_season":3,"id":433,"name":"test4","episode_count":9},{"last_season":2,"id":380,"name":"test2","episode_count":6},{"last_season":1,"id":434,"name":"test1","episode_count":7}]
```

Comment: `return ($r=strnatcmp($b["last_season"], $a["last_season"])) ? $r : $b["episode_count"] -$a["episode_count"] ;`

Answer (score 1):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return [$b['last_season'], $b['episode_count']] <=> [$a['last_season'], $a['episode_count']];
});
```